# iOS - Button background changes with gradient background on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have one view and on view several buttons. I have added a gradient background to view and background image to buttons. But my button's color is changing as gradient background goes down on iPad 6.0.

I have tried to add gradient background to view using both programatically and by adding a gradient image to view by:

```
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer greyGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

And

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyboard_BG.png"]];
```

But nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

> But my button's color is changing as gradient background goes down on iPad 6.0.

It sounds like the background image you're using for the buttons is semi-tranparent. Try removing the image, and instead setting an opaque background color. If that works, you'll probably need to edit the background image to make it fully opaque.